# ARC Toolkit Tab Not Showing in Chrome Devtools

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, accessibility

I am unable see ARC Toolkit (accessibility tool) in chrome devtools which was showing few days back. I am using Mac OS Chrome Version 117.0.5938.149.

I have also tried to fix issue using steps like uninstall and install ARC Toolkit extension and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use ARC Toolkit all the time but I'm on a PC, not a Mac.  It has not disappeared for me.

Are you sure you didn't install some other plugins and that cause "ARC Toolkit" to scroll of the end?  There's a double right arrow at the end

[image]

and when you click on it, you get a dropdown of other plugins.  That's where my ARC Toolkit is.

[image]

If you go to the "extensions" toolbar item, do you see ARC Toolkit in the list?

[image]

Comment: It was coming few week backs in chrome devtools alogn with other tabs like console, performance and sources etc but it is not displaying now.